# Form input validation doesn't work in angular forms (with plunkr)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDIT: PLUNKR is updated and demonstrates the issue!

I have a feeling my design is flawed, but I did the following:  (Simplified example of the issue:)

```
.directive('awesomeInput', function($log, $compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            'ngModel': '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.prepend(angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" name="awesome" required>'));
           $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

If I then use awesomeInput in a form, the issue I'm having is that the validators such as ng-minlength="0" or required do not seem to be enacted against the form property.

```
<form>
   <div awesome-input ng-model="formData.awesome"></div>   <!-- this won't validate properly -->
   <input type="text" ng-model="formData.first_name" required name="first_name">  <!-- this does -->
</form>
```

Here's the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/K7jsWOY6S7nxCMW0g3aC

To reproduce the error, simply notice that you can type less than 6 characters in the first input and no error shows up when you unfocus.  The second input does show the error properly.  If you check the html (view page source) you will notice both have the same markup and should work...

It seems the issue is related to the directive template.  If you take the error view markup out of the directive template and into the index.html, it actually shows the error correctly.

Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive also has the template shown here:

```
        template: '<div class="text-danger registrationError center-block" ng-show="form.awesome.$dirty && form.awesome.$invalid"><div ng-show="form.awesome.$error.minlength">MINLENGTH</div></div>'
```

Which is replying on form. But since your directive has an isolate scope, it's not behaving like you'd expect. Simply passing in the form to the directive seems to do the trick: http://plnkr.co/edit/TlgXH0mDf6nzj4v3fTiG?p=preview

```
// In isolate scope
'form': '='
// On directive form="form"
```

Now they both have the MINLENGTH error.

EDIT: addressing the naming issue.

This is actually a really cool bug. It turns out that the naming is important because if the priority of directives are the same, it evaluates them alphabetically! this means if your directive is lexicographically before ng-model, such as "awesome", it will evaluate yours first. But if it's after, like "sweaty" it will do the ng-model first.

In order to fix this, for any name, you just need to add a priority to your directive that is higher than the default priority (which ng-model uses) of 0.

```
priority: 1,
```

Here is a plnkr to play with that has this shown: http://plnkr.co/edit/y6jQa0NilQcgv0WcSCUH?p=preview

Really cool bug you found there!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I updated the plunkr to include this.  I am currently doing this, however, it still doesn't work in my project.  (It does in the plunkr though...)  I guess I still gotta isolate what is different about my scenario and post back here when I figure it out...

Comment: Cool, np, let me know if you get a failing plnkr and I'll take a look

Comment: it took a very long time before I finally tried simply changing the name of the directive to discover the issue.  But eventually, after approximately 12 hours or so of experimentation, I finally figured out that it works with certain directive names, like "awesomeInput" is OK but "sweatyBalls" is NOT OK.  I know you are thinking this guy obviously doesn't know about the dash you need in the markup i.e. "sweaty-balls" but indeed, I used the dash and it doesn't work.  I updated the plunkr.  Sorry if I don't sound chipper about this, it's perhaps the most annoying thing I've ever seen

Comment: Awesome bug! I know it's frustrating with weird bugs like this, but I've added an answer that should help explain this.

Comment: Oh man, you're totally right.  It's the priority!  Thanks so much for explaining this!