# What order are directives compiled in if they are the same priority?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the AngularJS docs it says (emphasis mine):

> Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. ***The order of directives with the same priority is undefined.*** The default priority is 0.

It looks like the [`inputDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0d034a98ec4ef1e0c3c1727e23d1ccd971ae74e6/src/ng/directive/input.js#L855) has no priority set, and neither does my custom directive (which is also has a post-link function). Why does my custom directive get run first in the chain of `$parsers` and `$formatters`?

It wasn't this way before `1.2.0rc-3`, in fact I had to raise the priority of my custom directive to get its parsers and formatters to run before the `inputDirective`.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined likely because it's up to the implementation of the browser to decide how objects get ordered.

As you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21636177/2728255): The order was defined alphabetically

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that seems plausible! It looks like the `inputDirective` doesn't have a name specified, though: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0d034a98ec4ef1e0c3c1727e23d1ccd971ae74e6/src/ng/directive/input.js#L855 Can you confirm if that's true? Because if it's named `inputDirective` then my custom directive (`restriction`) should be getting compiled after it, but it is being compiled before it right now.

Comment: Actually I see where it is being provided as a directive: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4c4537e65e6cf911c9659b562d89e3330ce3ffae/src/AngularPublic.js#L151-L152 and it is being used as two directives named `input` and `textarea` both of which would come before `restriction` alphabetically. What do you think?

Comment: well restriction is before textarea, so it probably matters which of the two you use?

Comment: wups, gotta brush up on my alphabet!! Using input